# Deletion protection in an Aurora cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Our application communicates with an AWS Aurora cluster containing two instances. When restoring a snapshot through CDK, the old (running) cluster is deleted automatically. On production however, deletion protection of the Aurora cluster will be enabled.

I (wrongly) assumed that by enabling deletion protection for the cluster, both cluster and instances part of the cluster are protected. However, instances running on an old cluster with deletion protection enabled are still deleted; the cluster itself is protected. All that is left is an empty Aurora cluster.

- Is there any way to also protect instances from being deleted, or is this not desired?
- What is the point of deletion protection when you end up with an empty Aurora cluster?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to protect instances from being deleted, or might this not be desired?

Yes, if you are using CloudFormation or AWS CDK, you can set the `DeletionPolicy` to `Retain` to preserve your cluster instances. Whether or not this is desirable depends on your specific use case.

> What is the purpose of deletion protection if you're left with an empty Aurora cluster?

The primary purpose is to safeguard your data. You can create a snapshot of the cluster, and then restore the database cluster from that snapshot to retrieve its last state.